# How to implement constraints in a Java program?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I was appearing for an interview where I was required to write a program to find the largest fibonacci number below N. While I successfully got the output for a lot of test cases, my code failed for *edge-test*.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;


class LargestFibonacciNumber{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        if(t<=Math.pow(10,4)){
            while (t-->0) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if(n > 0 && n<= Math.pow(10,9)){
                int result = largestFibonacciNumber(n);
            System.out.println(result);}
            
        }
        sc.close();
        }
        
    }

    static int largestFibonacciNumber(int n){
        
        
            if(n == 0){
            return 0;
        }

        int first = 0, second = 1;
        int third = first + second;

        while(third < n){
            first = second;
            second = third;
            third = first + second;
        }

        return second;
        
    }
}
```

This is the problem statement:

**Problem Description**

Given a number N, you have to find the largest Fibonacci number which is less than N.

**Input Format**

First line contains an integer T - Number of test cases.

Next T lines each have a given number N

**Output Format**

Print the answer for each test case in a separate line.

**Constraints**

T <= 10^4

0 < N <= 10^9

What could be the issue with my code which makes it fail the *edge-test*? I'm guessing it has got something to do with constraints which I'm unable to understand.

Comment: There is no need to be checking the constraints in your code, since they are guaranteed.

Comment: Your code returns the wrong answer for N=1

Comment: @MattTimmermans cheers mate, I added the condition to return 0 should n be equal to one and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition check for n = 1.

```
static int largestFibonacciNumber(int n){
    if(n == 1)
        return 0;

    int first = 0, second = 1;
    int third = first + second;

    while(third < n){
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = first + second;
    }
    return second;
}
```

Then it won't fail for n = 1, also n = 0 check is not needed since N is expected to be greater than 0

Comment: fib n=1 is 1 not 0! please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int largestFibonacciNumber(int n) {
    if (n == 1){
        return 0;
    } else {
        int[] fibonacciNumbers = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < fibonacciNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (i < 2) {
                fibonacciNumbers[i] = 1;
            } else {
                fibonacciNumbers[i] = fibonacciNumbers[i - 2] + fibonacciNumbers[i - 1];
            }
        }
        return fibonacciNumbers[n - 2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As [Matt Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483526/matt-timmermans) mentiond in comments section your code returns the wrong answer for `N = 1`.

Your code must return `1` when the `N = 1`.

You must change your first if's condition to something like this:

```java
if(n ==0 || n == 1)
    return n;

// or better way:
if(n <= 1)
    return n;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The correct result for `N = 1` is 0, because 0 is the largest Fibonacci number below 1; 1 is not below 1. And un-memoised recursion is the *least* efficient way to compute Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: The first 21 numbers in fibbonaci are `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765` so then `fib(1)` is `1`.  You can see it [here](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/fibonacci). About efficiency your right

Comment: The problem is not to find the Nth Fibonacci number, it is to find the largest Fibonacci number below N. 1 is not below 1 so it cannot be the correct output when N = 1.